# How to get enabled payments methods for store

Tags: php, shopify, payment

I've been developing an app in Shopify. Everything has been going well.
But now i need to get activated or enabled payment methods for the store.

For example, how to find out if the store owner has enabled Cash On Delivery (COD).
I've searched through Shopify docs and none helped me. 
I've also posted a question in their community forum. I'm not getting answers that much.

So, i am posting here hoping someone will help me.

Looking forward to your reply

Comment: this may help you https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/sell-in-person/payment-methods

Comment: Thanks bobi. This seems that i need to do it manually by going to admin panel. But what i want is to get the list of all available payment methods programmatically preferrably from PHP

Comment: you should have this code ready in your system check in "checkout/payment methods" there should be code to display all payment methods

Comment: Once again, i checked this page [payment methods](http://help.shopify.com/en/manual/sell-in-person/payment-methods) and couldn't find any code snippet or docs which can help me to get the payment methods. Could you direct me to the docs page you are describing.  Also, i want to get payment methods in all pages like home, product page. etc. So that i can show notification based on payment methods